# Regex - match returns None. Where am I wrong?

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'this is a test'
>>> reg1 = re.compile('test$')
>>> match1 = reg1.match(s)
>>> print match1
None
```

in Kiki that matches the test at the end of the s. What do I miss? (I tried `re.compile(r'test$')` as well)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use

```
match1 = reg1.search(s)
```

instead. The `match` function *only* matches at the start of the string ... see the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does by default).

Comment: thank you, I completely forgot about the difference between these two operations :)

Comment: Thanks! such a weird behavior of match() though :((
I spend two hours now, trying to figure out the problem in the rx lol

Comment: Ty. IMHO, it's completely counterintuitive...

Answer (score 2):

Your regex does not *match* the full string. You can use *search* instead as Useless mentioned, or you can change your regex to match the full string:

```
'^this is a test$'
```

Or somewhat harder to read but somewhat less useless:

```
'^t[^t]*test$'
```

It depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of that `match` method returns `None` if it couldn't find expected pattern, if it find the pattern it would return an object with type of `_sre.SRE_match` .

So, if you want Boolean (`True` or `False`) result from `match` you must check the result is `None` or not!

You could examine texts are matched or not somehow like this:

```
string_to_evaluate = "Your text that needs to be examined"
expected_pattern = "pattern"

if re.match(expected_pattern, string_to_evaluate) is not None:
    print("The text is as you expected!")
else:
    print("The text is not as you expected!")
```